# assigning a function parameter to a variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to call a function parameter and assign it to a variable. 
  the function gets the information as an array

```
function info($name,$email,$number){

 }

    //calling the function parameter $number from function


    $exten = call_user_func_array(info,$number);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$number` is a callable then you can just call it as `$number()`

Comment: i sloved the error i was having .. thank much for you effort

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the concepts, so I think this is what you want:

```
function info($needed){
    $name = "john";
    $email = "john@doe.com";
    $number = "555-5555";

    switch($needed) {
        case "name":
            return $name;
            break;
        case "email":
            return $email;
            break;
        case "number":
            return $number;
            break;
        default:
            return null;
    }
 }
    //calling the function parameter $number from function


    echo call_user_func("info","number");
```

Comment: thanks for your effort , but this is not what i looking for

Comment: can you show me where the error is in that line 
    $exten =  call_user_func_array("info", "$number");

Comment: In fact I couldn't understand what is the return expected in $exten

Comment: extent is supposed to return extension number eg(1234) from a server
the function ( info) establishes a connection to the server , it works cause other part of the program uses this function and i want to use this function

Comment: i solved out my error , i was doing some hard coding

Comment: Nice to know that haha... I was afraid I'll not being capable to help you more.